# We have devbridge/autocomplete installed, but I want to use jQuery UI autocomplete. How?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

We have devbridge autocomplete (https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete) in our Rails app. I'd like to use jQuery UI Autocomplete. Is there a way?

Comment: I don't see why not.  jQuery UI Autocomplete works regardless of the server-side technology.

Comment: Yeah, but the devbridge autocomplete javascript definition defines .autocomplete, so it overrides the jquery ui one. It also defines devbridgeAutocomplete. The devbridge docs imply that the ui one will override the devbridge one, but I have the opposite experience. I ended up just making due with the devbridge one. Not optimal, though.

Comment: Have you looked into [`jQuery.noConflict()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)?